# Improve raw tile corner

Tags: tile

I paid a contractor to install a shower for me. He did a decent job, but the “soap nook” edges look really rough.

[image: rough tile edge]

[image: rough title edge too]

I have since learned that I should have asked him to use rounded corners for the edges. But it is too late for that now. (I don’t really want to try to make him fix it.)

My question is if there is anything I can do from a DIY standpoint to improve these corners?

Comment: If the morter is on top of the tile you may be able to remove it, If the tile is broken have it replaced, It should have never been approved in its current condition. Overall you got a very poor job. Where is the trim on the front, the tile should not show. Get the contractor back and have it fixed correctly.

Comment: A good installer will know what to do without you having to ask for it. Some tile does not have any tile trim pieces available, but there are metal trim accessories from other vendors, if there is nothing available that the tile maker supplies.

Comment: You might be able to add outside metal corner trim to cover it up.

Comment: It needs "bull nose" tile for finished rounded edge.

Answer (score 1):

"He did a decent job"… No, he most certainly didn't. That's a classic case of "no clue, no care."

[image]

These edges should line up, the faces should be level, the edges should not have been cut with a blunt axe & he should have thought about what he was going to do with the unfinished faces. If there is no quarter-round for that tile, then he should have made best endeavour to use *clean* or uncut edges wherever visible or mentioned this could be the result without, and asked you which quarter-round you would prefer.

You're now going to have to cut that face back [red line] by the width of some quarter round.

He could also have bothered to finish off the grout properly [marked in blue]

Comment: What would I use to cut the tile back?  I am not a tile guy (which is why I hired it out) and I am worried I will crack the tile.

Comment: You're going to need something like an angle grinder. I'd get the so-called tiler back to fix that, don't DIY it if you have no experience. You'll make a worse job than he did. Tiling is only 'easy' if you have low expectation of the finish. Poor tiling is easy. Good tiling requires expertise. Patching up botch jobs requires both experience & attention to detail too.

Comment: Thanks!  I fear he will not have the expertise needed to fix it (and may make it worse). I may just have to live with it if there is no DIY level thing that can be done to improve it.

Comment: You can get both wooden & metal L-Trim which could be used to lap the edges.